# Can'nt run casWebApplication with BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'localeResolver' defined

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, cas

I tried to build and start the cas service from source, but failed.

The version information is as follows:

```bash
CAS Version: 6.6.10
CAS Branch: master
CAS Commit Id: Not Available
CAS Build Date/Time: 2023-07-13T09:04:58.751Z
Spring Boot Version: 2.7.3
Spring Version: 5.3.22
Java Home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
Java Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java Version: 11.0.19
JVM Free Memory: 213 MB
JVM Maximum Memory: 4 GB
JVM Total Memory: 435 MB
OS Architecture: aarch64
OS Name: Mac OS X
OS Version: 13.3
```

The error information is as follows:

```bash
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'localeResolver' defined in class path resource [org/apereo/cas/config/CasWebAppConfiguration.class]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=refresh; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.apereo.cas.config.CasWebAppConfiguration; factoryMethodName=localeResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/apereo/cas/config/CasWebAppConfiguration.class]] for bean 'localeResolver': There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=localeResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:295)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164)
    at org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplication.main(CasWebApplication.java:53)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'localeResolver' defined in class path resource [org/apereo/cas/config/CasWebAppConfiguration.class]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=refresh; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.apereo.cas.config.CasWebAppConfiguration; factoryMethodName=localeResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/apereo/cas/config/CasWebAppConfiguration.class]] for bean 'localeResolver': There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=localeResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] bound.
    at org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplication.main(CasWebApplication.java:56)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'localeResolver' defined in class path resource [org/apereo/cas/config/CasWebAppConfiguration.class]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=refresh; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.apereo.cas.config.CasWebAppConfiguration; factoryMethodName=localeResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/apereo/cas/config/CasWebAppConfiguration.class]] for bean 'localeResolver': There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=localeResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:295)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164)
    at org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplication.main(CasWebApplication.java:53)
```

I was able to build it successfully with the build command in the official documentation, but I couldn't launch it with the casWebApplication!